# Postman импортирует данные из CSV в кавычках - как их убрать?

Tags: csv, postman

Имеется файл csv в котором содержатся булевы значения, которые нужно передать в переменные без кавычек. Проблема в том, что при загрузке файла Postman воспринимает все не числовые значения, как строки и присваивает им кавычки автоматически. Возможно ли как то это обойти?

[image: Файл CSV]

[image: Preview data]

Answer (score 0):

В общем оказалось, что несмотря на кавычки булево значение обрабатывается нормально и они не учитываются при подстановке в переменные. Однако, чтобы вопрос не был просто так закрыт, оставляю решение для тех, кто действительно столкнётся с такой проблемой, что булевы значения будут строкой восприниматься. Поскольку у нас только два варианта (правда, ложь), решил задачу через банальное условие:

```
// Получаем значение из csv файла
let сardValue = pm.variables.get("hasValue");

// Условие, изменяющее строковое значение на булево (тип динамически определяется)
virtCard == "true" ? virtCard = true : virtCard == "false" ? virtCard = false : virtCard = "битые данные";

// записываем полученное булево значение в переменную
pm.collectionVariables.set("card_status", virtCard)
```